# ModuleNotFoundError: No module Openpyxl found

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm learning python and  I want to create a simple script to analyze some data from an excel file. I'm reading [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/python-excel-tutorial) and it suggest to install the openpyxl library using the command `pip install openpyxl`

I've this code into my python file at the moment

```py
# Test script for xls manipulation
import openpyxl

# Loading file xlsx
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('BEVANDE.xlsx')
```

And if I try to run it using vs code debugger I will get this error

```
No module named 'openpyxl'
```

I've readed into another similar question that pip command will install the module only for python 2 and someone suggested to use pip3 install command but I will get this messages into console

```
Requirement already satisfied: Openpyxl in c:\python312\lib\site-packages (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\python312\lib\site-packages (from Openpyxl) (1.1.0)
```

How I can fix this and what is the correct way to import and install modules in python?

Comment: This type of error invariably means you're not using the same python binary that is associated with "c:\python312".   What python binary is VSCode Debugger using?

Comment: not sure, how I can check?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602151/how-to-change-interpreter-in-visual-studio-code might help you.

Comment: Probably, you aren't using the correct `Python` version, or, the dependency was installed outside of the `venv` while VS Code opens a `venv`. If you're on Windows, try creating a new `venv` with `python -m venv venv` from an administrator shell. Then, enter it with `.\venv\Scripts\activate`. Then, you can retry installing `openpyxl` and rerun the script. If you're on Linux, then it's `source venv/bin/activate` to enter the `venv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the environment variables of your python path.
you might installed openpyxl in another version of your python.

like you installed openpyxl in python 3.12, but you're running code on another version 2.xx, not 3.12.

Check the code you are trying to run is executing in the correct Python version.

Answer (score 2):

Might even be worth having a look at anaconda for your python environoments because as you get more proficient, all these packages that you're installing via the console will just make everything messy

So have a look at anaconda and you can create virtual environoments to run your code on, i.e first create your conda environoment, then activate that environoment, conda install pip, pip install openpyxl.

Then finally navigate to where your code folder is using cd then just type code followed by  a dot.

Which will load your code using that python environoment. Then for example if you want to put it on github for others to use too. You can just provide that environoment you created and people can just load that up quick and easy